# how to set text Field value in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uitextfield, double

i have tried update the value of text fields but they are show the old values,

code--

```
double lastValue;
lastValue = [strLastval doubleValue];
textPriceAtExp.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",lastValue];
```

frist time show the correct value but enter the text fields value show the old values.

the lastValue gaine  the html data.
any help plz
thanks

Comment: Where is called this code ? We need more code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is that the UITextField you created in IB is actually connected to the UITextField in your code (textPriceAtExp).

Comment: yes;  connected to the UITextField in textPriceAtExp. and frist time show the  correct values but enter the new value in textPriceAtExp ,the text field show the old values, and all calculation is go to the new values.

Answer (score 0):

The codes are too few. So all I can help you is to guess what happens. Maybe the **textPriceAtExp** is nil, because it is a property, not a member variable. Maybe the strLastval is the old value, so nothing is wrong.

You can use NSLog() to check some value of the variables in codes.